# how to use string **skip-soteri-security-check** in the commit message in git commit message

Tags: git, cluster-computing

how to include the string **skip-soteri-security-check** in the git commit message to skip the vulnerability scanning

git commit -m "updated cluster name **skip-soteri-security-check**"

git commit -m "**skip-soteri-security-check** updated cluster name"

git commit -m **skip-soteri-security-check** "updated cluster name"

non of these worked

Comment: Several of these commands would achieve the result you asked for. Probably the result you're asking for ("include string skip-soteri-security-check") is not the result you actually need (which depends on whatever this "soteri" thing is).

Comment: I just wanted to bypass the vulnerability scan so that I can commit and push the changes to my repo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [Soteri's product Security for Bitbucket](https://soteri.io/products/security-for-bitbucket). To [skip the security hook for a single commit](https://docs.soteri.io/security-for-bitbucket/latest/how-to-bypass-the-pre-receive-hook-for-a-single-co), the commit message has to include the special string (including the asterisks), e.g.

```
git commit -m '**skip-soteri-security-check**'
```

This feature was [added in version 2.5.0](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221399/security-for-bitbucket-enhanced-secret-scanner-by-soteri/version-history), so make sure that you're using that version or newer.

***DISCLAIMER*:** I am a developer of Security for Bitbucket who works at Soteri.